# Python 'Series' object has no attribute 'split' Error in CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am preprocessing the data in a CSV file using python and pandas. I am getting this error : 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'.

Here is the code segment.

```
def load_data():
data = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Project/Uber_Ride_Reviews.csv')
return data

tweet_df = load_data()
tweet_df.head()
tweet_df.drop_duplicates(subset='ride_review',keep=False, inplace=True)
print(tweet_df)

def removeStopWords(text):
        clean_word_list = [word for word in text.split() if word not in stoplist]
        return clean_word_list
```

And the following code segment gives the error mentioned above.

```
tweet_df['removeStopwords']=removeStopWords(tweet_df['text'])
```

Complete description of the error is as follows.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-21-be4e0c836a5b> in <module>()

--> 101 tweet_df['removeStopwords']=removeStopWords(tweet_df['text'])
    102 
    103 

3 frames pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in
__getattr__(self, name)    5177             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):    5178    return self[name]
-> 5179             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)    5180     5181     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'
```

How can i fix the issue? Thank you in advance

Comment: `text.str.split()` in your function. But I'm not sure that's what you want.

Comment: Use `tweet_df['removeStopwords']=tweet_df['text'].apply(removeStopWords)`

Comment: Great. It worked @jezrael